# Why can't I add the tag malaria?

Tags: support

I just asked a question, regarding the risk on malaria in Thailand:

[Where in Thailand should I be cautious about malaria?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/where-in-thailand-should-i-be-cautious-for-malaria)

Tagging it with the tag "malaria" only seems logical. How many times I try, the tag does not show. Is this related to my new achieved role as protector? Before I could add tag, as I like.

Comment: -1 and no comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[malaria](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaria) is [synonym](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/health/synonyms) to the [health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), so you can't.

Comment: it should have popped up suggesting that it was now [tag:health]...?

Comment: Yes I don't know who voted you down. I think Dori made the malaria and dengue fever tags synonyms of health some time ago.